# Turn mysql rows into columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table that has a status column, the status is a number between 1-8.

I can use the query

```
SELECT status, COUNT(id) AS total 
FROM cart_orders 
GROUP BY status;
```

To get a result that looks like:

```
status | total
1      | 10
2      | 15
3      | 8
4      | 51
5      | 65 
...
```

But that means every time I need the data I have to do:

```
$status = array(1 => null, 2 => null, 3 => null, 4 => null, 
                5 => null, 6 => null, 7 => null, 8 => null);

foreach($rows as $row){
    $status[$row['status']] = $row['total'];
}
```

Which, while not a lot of code I would like to avoid having to do that,

What I want is to modify the query so I end up with a single row that looks like:

```
1  | 2  | 3  | 4  | 5   
10 | 15 | 8  | 51 | 65 ...
```

so I can just go e.g. `$row['4']`

The only what I can think of to do this would be to have each column as a subquery, which I would rather use the code than have 8 sub-queries. The other option is to join the table on itself 7 times, but that is assumedly also not ideal?

How else could I do this?

Comment: http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#78

Comment: Ah, of course! this works `COUNT(IF(STATUS = 1, id, NULL)) AS s1, 
COUNT(IF(STATUS = 2, id, NULL)) AS s2`

Comment: @Hailwood better use `preparedStatement` for that. what if you have 100 types of status? then your query will be very long :D see my answer below how to create preparedstatements.

Comment: @JohnWoo Would love to, unfortunately the framework (Code Igniter) does not support them :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are asking to do is called a "pivot query," which MySQL unfortunately does not support natively.  What you must do is specify each row individually, as in:

```
SELECT
   SUM(IF (status = 1, total, 0)) AS '1'
   ...
```

..but this is very verbose -- especially if you have a lot of columns.  I think your PHP is a little more verbose than it needs to be too in that you don't need to declare the array ahead of time.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the query you want to change, but how you display the information you get from it.
Try something like this

```
// insert code to whatever defines your $rows variable

$string1 = "<tr>";
$string2 = "<tr>";
foreach($rows as $row) {
  $string1 .= "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
  $string2 .= "<td>" . $row['total'] . "</td>";
}
$string1 .= "</tr>\n";
$string2 .= "</tr>\n";

echo "<table border=\"1\">\n";
echo $string1;
echo $string2;
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: It's not for outputting in a table. It is for displaying the amount of items in that group in a nav, as such I need to know what each row means.